# Struggeling with defining subclass of tkinter frame (in python) which should let user choose which part of content to display

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a class in Python (using Tkinter) whom I can pass multiple Widgets to store them; of these widgets, the class should always display only one in a frame, and when I press a button, a drop-down menu should open from which I can choose which one of the widgets the frame should go on displaying.

My actual implementation of this idea is working pretty well, but only when I put only one of these frames into a window. As soon as I define more than one, they start to behave oddly...

**One example**:

I used the class and gave it three Tkinter labels as an input. One of these Labels displays the text "Label 1", the second the text "Label 2" and the third the text "Label 3".
I then .pack() the whole thing into my label and it works fine. This is how it looks:
[image of the widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbOA1.png)

When I click on the '+'-Button, it unwraps like this:
[image of the widget with all Labels displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qMge.png)

And when I click on the 'x'-Button, it goes back to its initial state. When I, however, click on the radio button next to 'Label 2', it goes back to its initial state, but now displaying 'Label 2' instead of 'Label 1':
[widget now displaying label 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WYRk.png)

So far, It's doing exactly what I want it to do: I can switch between multiple sub-widgets using one widget in which they stay contained.

However, the problems start as soon as I try to put multiple of these things into a single window. I tried to put one into the window containing "Label 1"-"Label 3", one containing "Label 4"-"Label 6" and one containing "Label 7"-"Label 9". The problem is that when I press the "+"-Button of one of them, all of them start to show their whole content (so suddenly, I have "Label 1"-"Label 9" unwrapped and not only "Label 1"-"Label 3"). As long as they are closed, they look somewhat like this: [weird formatted stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGi4I.png)
And that's how it looks when I have clicked the "+"-Button: [all contents wrapped out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YVWB.png)

I think the reason for all of them unwrapping at once is that for some reason, the buttons (the '+'- and 'x'-Button) call the specified function in ALL of the frames at once, not only in the one it's in. I tried to fix this using lambda whilst specifying the function the buttons should call, but it is still not working.

I am not a native english speaker, so sorry if my explanation seems a little weard, and also, I have all my python knowledge from learning-by-doing and the internet, so also sorry if I mess up the words for everything a little. Maybe my code helps explayning the problem a little better:

```
class MultiInput(Frame):
"""use .add(Widged)-Method to add widged!"""
subs = []
adders = []
index = 0
def __init__(self, parent):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.indexVar = IntVar()
    self.indexVar.set(0)
    self.dropdown = Button(self, text="+", command=self.drop)
    self.dropdown.grid(row=0, column=0)
    self.dropup = Button(self, text="x", command=self.undrop)

def drop(self):
    num = -1
    self.dropdown.grid_forget()
    self.dropup.grid(row=0, column=0)
    for i in range(0, len(self.subs)):
        num += 1
        if i != self.index:
            self.subs[i].grid(column=1, row=num+1)
            self.adders[i].grid(column=0, row=num+1)

def undrop(self):
    for i in range(0, len(self.subs)):
        self.subs[i].grid_forget()
        self.adders[i].grid_forget()
    self.subs[self.index].grid(row=0, column=1)
    self.dropup.grid_forget()
    self.dropdown.grid(row=0, column=0)


def add(self, Widged):
    if len(self.subs) == 0:
        self.subs.append(Widged)
        self.adders.append(Radiobutton(self,
            variable = self.indexVar, 
            command = self.change,
            value = 0))
        self.change()
    else:
        self.subs.append(Widged)
        self.adders.append(Radiobutton(self,
            variable = self.indexVar, 
            command = self.change,
            value = len(self.subs) - 1))

def change(self):
    self.index = self.indexVar.get()
    self.undrop()
```

and here is how I called it in my first example, where it is perfectly working:

```
root = Tk()

multi = MultiInput(root)
multi.add(Label(multi, text="Label 1"))
multi.add(Label(multi, text="Label 2"))
multi.add(Label(multi, text="Label 3"))
multi.pack()
```

As soon as I ad this to the end of the code (to add mere than one MultiInput), it starts doind the stuff from my second example:

```
multi2 = MultiInput(root)
multi2.add(Label(multi2, text="Label 4"))
multi2.add(Label(multi2, text="Label 5"))
multi2.add(Label(multi2, text="Label 6"))
multi2.pack()

multi3 = MultiInput(root)
multi3.add(Label(multi3, text="Label 7"))
multi3.add(Label(multi3, text="Label 8"))
multi3.add(Label(multi3, text="Label 9"))
multi3.pack()
```

So here comes my question: How can I get the buttons to call the function they should call so that they only use it on the Object they are supposed to use it on? Or do I have an entirely wrong idea of using classes in Python?

Comment: Your `subs` and `adders` lists were created in the class itself, and are shared by every instance of the class.  You need to create them in `__init__()` instead, so that each instance has its own lists.

Comment: Thank you very much, I fixed this and now, it's working. Great, I'll remember it for further use of classes and objects!

Comment: I'm aware I am a little late to be saying that, but since you helped me instantly resolve my problem back then (3 years ago), you might want to consider making your comment an answer (even if it contains just the same content as the comment) so I can mark it as the accepted answer.